# Setting a duration on multiple video's on the same page

Tags: jquery, html, video, html5-video

I am loading multiple video's on the same page (within a carousel), and for each individual video I would like to set the duration of the video. The code below shows 2 examples, one trying to make it work for each video using jQuery `.each()`, and another that works, but only for the first video and subsequently it applies the same duration to each video.

How can I get the jQuery to loop through the video's one by one?

Thanks!

**Each (Does not work)**

```
var video = document.getElementById('video');

// Set video duration in caption
video.each(function () {
    this.addEventListener('loadedmetadata', function() {
        // vars
        var total = video.duration.toFixed(0); // Total number of seconds with 0 decimal places
        var minutes = Math.floor(total / 60); // Seconds divided by 60 to get total minutes
        var seconds = total % 60; // Seconds remaining once minutes are removed

        $('.duration .time').text(minutes + ":" + seconds + "s");
    });
});
```

**Individual (Does work but applies same duration to all videos)**

```
var video = document.getElementById('video');

// Set video duration in caption
video.addEventListener('loadedmetadata', function() {
    // vars
    var total = video.duration.toFixed(0); // Total number of seconds with 0 decimal places
    var minutes = Math.floor(total / 60); // Seconds divided by 60 to get total minutes
    var seconds = total % 60; // Seconds remaining once minutes are removed

    $('.duration .time').text(minutes + ":" + seconds + "s");
});
```

HTML

```
<div class="video-wrapper">
    <video id="video" src="URL" poster="POSTER URL" preload></video>
</div>

<div class="meta">
    <h5 class="duration"><span class="time"></span></h5>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

The reason the first one doesn't work is because you're applying `each` to a single element, plus the syntax is all wrong

Assuming your setup actually has multiple video tags, this would be a better way to do it

```
var videos = $('video');

videos.each(function () {
    $(this).on('loadedmetadata', function(e) {
        // vars

        var total = e.target.duration.toFixed(0); // Total number of seconds with 0 decimal places
        var minutes = Math.floor(total / 60); // Seconds divided by 60 to get total minutes
        var seconds = total % 60; // Seconds remaining once minutes are removed

        $('.duration .time').text(minutes + ":" + seconds + "s");
    });
});
```

Even so, your setup only has a single duration display, so it will show the duration of the last video to load